# 404 when deploying angular cli app to Wamp server

Tags: angular-cli, wampserver

I have an application built with Angular Cli. I can open the default view without a problem but when I try to access another part of the page I get the following error message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /myapp/calendar/2017-11-04 was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 Server at localhost Port 8099
```

The route for calendar is defined like this:

```
 {path: 'calendar/:id', component: CalendarComponent},
```

I do not know if this is a problem my angular app or if it is a problem with Wamp server. Any suggestions on where I should start looking?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an URL Rewrite rule on the server corresponding to the `<base href="/myapp/">` value in `index.html` to make the server ignore the routes handled by the Angular router. So the server returns `index.html` for those routes, which in turn will bootstrap the app and take care of the route. You can read about that subject at [Routing helper: MapSpaFallbackRoute](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices#routing-helper-mapspafallbackroute)

Something like (acually this RegEx is wrong. You need to ignore files with extensions, like script names.)

```
RewriteRule ^myapp\/.+ myapp/index.html
```

I am not an expert in Wamp, so you can read the following tutorial [How to make mod_rewrite work on wamp](http://blog.cmstutorials.org/tutorials/tips-tricks/how-to-make-mod_rewrite-work-on-wamp)